# Can I Make a windows boot usb on eOS 6.0?

Tags: system

I Used linux as a last resort to recover my pc but now that i have, i want to go back without spending £100 on media
Is it possible to make one on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Technically*, yes ... but it'll be a right pain in the bum. Generally speaking, there are two ways to make a Windows installation USB when your main computer does not run Windows:

1. Borrow a friend or family member's Windows machine for 15 minutes and [follow these steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d)
2. The VM-shuffle:

   1. [Download a Windows 10 ISO file](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO)
   2. Install it in a VirtualBox VM (You will not need to activate Windows for this installation, as it's being used only for an hour)
   3. Have the USB stick you plan to use auto-assigned to be passed through to the Windows VM (so it's never mounted by the host)
   4. Visit the link in the first option and follow those steps to create a bootable USB stick

   <sup>**Note:** If you have a remarkably powerful computer, you can skip steps 1 and 2 by [downloading a pre-made Virtual Box VM from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). I am using a 9th Generation Core i7 with 32GB RAM for development and these VMs are just about the only thing that ever get the processor fans spinning at their maximum velocity.</sup>

For the second option, I find that the process fails 90% of the time when *not* using a Samsung or SanDisk USB stick. For the first option, just about any device that claims to be a flash-based USB storage device will work.

Comment: This Should Work? Brilliant!!! I'll let you know on my outcome